# Manipulating & Traversing trees

Tags: generics, recursion, tree, tree-traversal

I'm stuck on an assignment not sure where to begin, the assignment is based on traversing and manipulating trees I have to read the tree data from a textfile, and  I have to implement•    Recursive preorder traversal
•   Recursive postorder traversal
•   Breadth-first traversal (does not need to be recursive).

I honestly don't know where to begin and I'm not asking for someone to give me the answer but guide me on what classes to create to start the assignment etc.. please would be appreciate

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.  This is aimed more at specific programming questions.  You'll likely need to post a valid attempt to code these concepts to get help here.

Comment: Most of all, "I have to read tree data" is not at all specific enough.  What is the file format?  Show the code you've written for a **node** class (value and references to other nodes).  I also strongly recommend that you start with a "tree dump" function that will print out a tree in a form you can read nicely; this will be important to debugging later.